# Make Resharper's quick documentation standard in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio, resharper

I recently found out about my Resharpers plugin function "Quick Documentation". This function is pretty damn sweet because it shows much more detailed code documentation than VS2008 standard layout and it also nicer to look at. I love using it, but the problem is that I have to press Ctrl+Q every time to view it.

Is there any way to overwrite the VS2008 popup code documentation with Resharper's quick documentation?

I have looked in several forums, including Jetbrian's but have not found anything to confirm nor deny if it is possible.

*PS. If you know how to do it in VS2010 aswell it would be sweet to, though not my priority at the moment.*

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 points to not to do so:

1. Usually, popup should show documentation summary. Otherwise, popup window will be too large for comfort use
2. ReSharper plugs into standard VS popup window. In VS2008, popup window could contain only plain text - advanced markup features in popup appears only since VS2010

Comment: You might have a point with your point 1. However it could be nice to try it out (if possible), and then I can decide if I find the popup window to large or not.